# Initializing custom init gives "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'initWithCoord:'"

Tags: objective-c, struct, initialization, location, parameter-passing

I creating my own class with a custom initWithCoord that takes one (struct CLLocationCoordinate2D*) as parameter.

Even though I think I have the correct parameter type, I still get the "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'initWithCoord:" What am I doing wrong:

PeopleStub.m:

```
#import "PeopleStub.h"


@implementation PeopleStub


-(id)initWithCoord:(struct CLLocationCoordinate2D*)coord{
    if(self = [super init]){
            people = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    }

    return self; 

}

@end
```

PeopleStub.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface PeopleStub : NSObject {

    NSMutableDictionary *people;

}

-(id)initWithCoord:(struct CLLocationCoordinate2D*)coord;

@end
```

My way of creating an instance of PeopleStub:

```
PeopleStub *peopleStub = [[PeopleStub alloc] initWithCoord:locationManager.location.coordinate;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to be passing just the `CLLocationCooridnate2D`, not a pointer to same as the parameter. So:

```
-(id)initWithCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;
```

Comment: Thanks! When I do that I get: "Expected ')' before 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'" and "Pervious declaration of '--(id)initWithCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord'". Why do I get that? It feels like it's refereing to another similar declaration.

Comment: @Nicsoft, sounds like you need to update both the declaration (.h) and definition (.m) files so that they match signatures. As an aside, this is basically C stuff. Getting a copy of a good book on C would probably make this all much easier for you in the long run.

Comment: I've done that. The warning "Previous declaration of '--(id)initWithCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord'" disappears but not the error "Expected ')' before 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'".

Comment: @Nicsoft, which line (.h or .m) gets the error? Can you edit your answwer to show the exact current code? It'll be much easier to help if we can see some code.